High efficiency method to query chain db
I am running two archive nodes, one is using Geth and the other Erigon. I have to run a pretty heavy duty indexing process, and making JSON-RPC calls to fetch the data is not fast enough, even if the service is hosted on the same machine running the nodes.
My question is, is there a library / is there a way to make the data-fetching process for heavy duty applications more efficient? Probably by completely skipping the JSON-RPC protocol and fetching from the chain db directly? If there isn't, would it be a good investment for me to research and actually build one myself? Would the improvement in speed be significant, or is JSON-RPC already pretty efficient by itself?
